# How to remove root backdoor on an Allwinner device?

Tags: root-access

I read on [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/09/allwinners_allloser_custom_kernel_has_a_nasty_root_backdoor/) that a root backdoor is triggered by writing `rootmydevice` to the special file `/proc/sunxi_debug/sunxi_debug`. That gives the current running process root privileges. If that file is present on your device or single-board computer, then you need to get rid of it. This is the code that checks for the magic write:

```
if(!strncmp("rootmydevice",(char*)buf,12)){
    cred = (struct cred *)__task_cred(current);
    cred->uid = 0;
    cred->gid = 0;
    cred->suid = 0;
    cred->euid = 0;
    cred->euid = 0;
    cred->egid = 0;
    cred->fsuid = 0;
    cred->fsgid = 0;
    printk("now you are root\n");
}
```

I have questions:

1. I have a Fusion5 tablet (which is rooted) manufactured by Allwinner with sun8I chipset using kernel 3.4.39. The file `/proc/sunxi_debug/sunxi_debug` is zero length. If the code is present, which file (if any) would it be in?
2. When using Terminal Emulator, I do `rm /proc/.sunxi_debug/sunxi_debug`, I get "Permission denied". `sudo su` gets "sudo: not found". How do I delete the `/proc/sunxi_debug/sunxi_debug` file?

Comment: To get root access, you only need to call `su`, no need `sudo su` (because there's no `sudo` on Android).

Comment: I just want you to note that the /proc is populated at every reboot and the kernel can recreate that file, should it need to. The correct way is to patch the kernel appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I think that the best idea is simply not to have Debug Mode set since the following quote seems to imply that is what lets the back door open:
"Its Linux 3.4-based kernel code, on Github here, contains what looks to The Register like a debug mode the authors forgot to kill.".

Am I correct in the above and am I correct in not deleting the file /proc/sunxi_debug/sunxi_debug since it is zero length.

PS the original article on this back door is at:
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/09/allwinners_allloser_custom_kernel_has_a_nasty_root_backdoor/

Comment: I'm going to try this tonight, but I'd wager you can change the write permissions of sunxi_debug.

Comment: `/proc` is a virtual file system, and its contents is determined by the running kernel. You're not going to be able to `rm` (or probably even `chmod`) the file, regardless of root or not. In order to get rid of the backdoor, you need to recompile the kernel w/o the backdoor code. [Not an answer, because compile the kernel is a far from trivial step...] Maybe you could use SELinux to block access to the file, not sure. Or create a kernel module to do so.